# How do i remove special characters in output print (brackets, the (') and the comma)

Tags: python

My code :

```
a='hello'
b= 10
c=a, b
print (c)
```

The output :

```
('hello', 10)
```

the output i want :

> hello 10

basically i want to remove the ' , ()
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a list of all the ways:

```
#Using f-strings
print(f"{a} {b}")

#List Method
print(*c)

#For Loops
for i in c:
   print(i,end=" ") #MAKES NO SENSE AT ALL. But is a method.

#String Concatenation
print(a+b)

#Print Normally
print(a, b)
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `print (c)` with `print(*c)`.

Answer (score 0):

There are just so many ways of doing that, but I suggest using f-strings
i.e.

```
print(f"{a} {b}")
```